# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6

Tags: json, jq

The 1 liner to grab the ticker works fine from commandline, but i get this error running in a script.

I run the 1 liner that grabs TICKERD from commandline, that doesnt give me the error.

But, i believe it is because of empty data in the array?

```
curl -k -s https://api.earningscalendar.net/?date=20190518
[]
```

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..15}
do
newdate=`/bin/date -v +"$i"d +%Y%m%d`
TICKERD=`curl -k -s https://api.earningscalendar.net/?date=$newdate | jq -r 'map([.ticker, .when] | join(", ")) | join("\n")' | grep -w "$1"`
TICKERA=`echo $TICKERD | cut -d, -f1`
if [ "$TICKERA" == "$1" ]
then
echo $TICKERD "is on" $newdate
exit
fi
done
```

Error Message :

```
./earnings.sh ADSK
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
ADSK, amc is on 20190523
```

Comment: Perhaps you should look at what you get back as a response? You're probably getting something back that isn't json once you calculate that date. Same goes for the `newdate` variable.

Answer (score 7):

To debug the problem, you could check the output produced by the "curl" command.  When I run it in a loop, without jq, the output is frequently "Retry later", as though there is some kind of throttling.

A similar alternative to consider would be to run a very basic jq program, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..15}
do
    newdate=`/bin/date -v +"$i"d +%Y%m%d`
    echo newdate=$newdate
    curl -k -s "https://api.earningscalendar.net/?date=$newdate" | jq type
done
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and turns out the curl command was returning header info that was stored in the env var, but suppressed by echo so it didn't appear to me.

Changing from `$ curl -iX ...` to `$ curl -X ...` discarded the header info and it started working.

Please see https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html for reference.

Comment: THIS. In my case, the headers were separated by `\r`, and `echo $RESPONSE` appeared to display just the body.

Answer (score 2):

An empty array will not cause the error message you see.

**EDIT:** the issue is the API returning retry later as [@peak says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56137550/4248931). To fix this, just add sleep 1 as that seemed to fix it

Here is an example of an empty array being returned but no parse error
`curl -k -s https://api.earningscalendar.net/?date=20190303 | jq -r 'map([.ticker, .when] | join(", ")) | join("\n")' | grep -w "$1"`

```
newdate=`date +%Y%m%d`
curl -k -s https://api.earningscalendar.net/?date=$newdate | jq -r 'map([.ticker, .when] | join(", ")) | join("\n")' | grep -w "$1"
```

Output

```
ACB, amc
TLRY, amc
CYBR, bmo
NEWR, amc
AEYE, amc
A, amc
USAT, --
RL, bmo
HUD, bmo
CATB, bmo
ROSE, amc
PAGS, amc
HDB, --
KOOL, amc
CPIX, amc
NLST, amc
AUPH, amc
VCTR, amc
ONCE, --
EVC, --
FSM, amc
JAPAY, --
VLVLY, --
RDSMY, --
ZLNDY, --
GNMSF, --
DOX, amc
PORBF, --
GDS, bmo
EGHT, amc
BEST, bmo
TAC, bmo
TIER, --
GOSS, bmo
AZZ, bmo
TRWH, amc
MDOMF, --
AUTL, bmo
ROAN, amc
CPLG, amc
CTST, bmo
DSSI, bmo
IMXI, amc
TCS, amc
MIXT, bmo
KDMN, --
SFST, --
ALLT, bmo
ARA, --
KMDA, bmo
OCX, amc
MXWL, --
HYGS, bmo
PANL, amc
MTNB, bmo
LIQT, bmo
APTX, bmo
REED, amc
MRBK, --
UQM, amc
GECC, bmo
TGEN, bmo
ENT, amc
MOGO, amc
SLGG, amc
EYEN, bmo
HCAP, bmo
WYY, amc
BLRX, bmo
SUNW, amc
TST, bmo
AYTU, bmo
XELB, bmo
ONTX, bmo
FTD, --
TCON, amc
CYTR, --
YOGA, amc
DYNT, bmo
CYCC, amc
DARE, amc
ESEA, --
EMES, --
ASCMA, --
NSPR, bmo
OPGN, amc
AGHC, --
LIOPF, --
```

Comment: Thank You for your input. I printed newdate and all 15 dates returned, so i know it is valid. Will check again.

Comment: See peaks input

Comment: Not sure but i still continue to get the same error. The newdate has no issues with returning. I believe the empty array is enclosed by [] which is why the error might be throwing in shell.

Comment: Interestingly when I run your code it doesn't produce any errors for me

Comment: The error is not caused by the empty array, I observed this behavior and provided an example above showing that it does not throw an error when an empty array is returned